# iverilog: Syntax error in assignment statement l-value

Tags: syntax, verilog

Why do I get syntax errors in my Verilog code?

The code:

```
module RegFile (
    input clk,
    input [4:0] rs1,
    input [4:0] rs2,
    input [4:0] wr,
    input reg[31:0] wd,
    input RegWrite,
    output reg[31:0] rd1,
    output reg[31:0] rd2);

    reg [31:0] file[31:0];

    integer i;
    initial begin
        i=0;
        while(i<32)
        begin
            file[i]=32'b0;
            i=i+1;
    end

assign rd1=file[rs1];
assign rd2=file[rs2];

always @(posedge clk) begin
    if(RegWrite)
        file[wr]=wd;
end

always@(file[0])
file[0]=32'b0;
    
endmodule
```

Here are the errors:

```
regfile.v:25: syntax error
regfile.v:27: Syntax in assignment statement l-value.
```

Answer (score 0):

The "l-value" syntax error happens because you make continuous assignments (using the `assign` keyword) to signals you declared as `reg`.  You should not use the `reg` keyword in this case.  Change:

```
output reg[31:0] rd1,
output reg[31:0] rd2);
```

to:

```
output [31:0] rd1,
output [31:0] rd2);
```

I also get a compile error on the following line:

```
input reg[31:0] wd,
```

You should not use the `reg` keyword for an `input` port.  Change it to:

```
input [31:0] wd,
```

Finally, you are missing the matching `end` keyword for the `while` `begin`:

```
initial begin
    i=0;
    while(i<32)
    begin
        file[i]=32'b0;
        i=i+1;
    end // <----- add this
end
```

You can sign up for a free account on edaplayground to gain access to simulators which will give you more specific error messages.